# Run GuixSD distribution on raspberrypi

Tags: linux

How we can load a guixsd distribution on raspberry pi? 
As you know guix is a unix package and guixsd is an operation system that has guix inside itself.

In the below link is the different download package of guix and guixsd, which is suitable?
http://guix.gnu.org/download/

I am newbie to raspberry pi, is there any tutorial?
Which version of raspberry pi is more suitable? 3 or 4?

in [this link](http://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Building-the-Installation-Image.html#Building-the-Installation-Image) there is an instruction for build image for beaglebone (that has u-boot), but for raspberry pi i don't how to do that.

In [this link](https://guix.gnu.org/blog/2017/porting-guixsd-to-armv7/) is also another tutorial about run guixsd on beaglebone.

Comment: you *may* want the `GNU Guix 1.0.1 Binary

Self-contained tarball providing binaries for Guix and its dependencies, to be installed on top of your Linux-based system`  - the armhf version ... perhaps

Comment: @jaromanda-x how i install above package, is there any similar tutorial that you introduce me?

Comment: follow the *Installation instructions* link on the page you linked to ... http://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Binary-Installation.html

Answer (score 1):

If you treat the non-free boot firmware like people treat BIOS/EFI on
x86 systems, and leave it up to the end-user to set that up, it's
probably technically possible.

There may be some drivers that require non-free firmware (e.g. wireless)
that will not work with Guix's linux-libre kernel.

The two options I see would be to add support for the boot configuration
used by the raspberry pi firmware, or for a little more flexible option,
configure the raspberry pi firmware to load u-boot and then use the
existing infrastructure to generate u-boot configuration files.

Since there's at least one major non-free component involved, I'm not
quite sure how it all sits with following the FSDG:

https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-system-distribution-guidelines.html

Though, one could treat that like BIOS/EFI on x86...

---

Source: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-guix/2019-10/msg00228.html by Vagrant Cascadian